# Git: disable configuration in user folder

Tags: git

I have my user's directory on windows mapped to network drive. 
When I work offline or with bad connection this network drive disconnects. And git starts complaining that it could not access `~/.gitconfig` file. Is there a way that I will say to git to not look at this path and point it to another specific location?